# Whats is the translation for "practical driving test pass certificate" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Whats is the translation for  "practical driving test pass certificate" in German?

Comment: What did dictionaries and online translation services reveal? Why has that not been sufficient to answer your question?

Comment: What is it in English?

Comment: @Eller   That's a good question. But perhaps it is simply *practical driving test pass certificate*?

Comment: I vote for re-opening the question. Rationale: as such a thing does not exist in German (speaking countries), Nafmee (who is asking) can hardly look it up in a dictionary. (There is yet no "German Dictionary of Non-existing Things".) Rather the task would be to find a suiting name for a thing like that e.g. for cases when you have to refer to it in an other country's context. Candidates for such a word: ***Fahrprüfungsbescheinigung***, ***Fahrprüfungszeugnis***, ***Fahrprüfungsschein***.

Comment: @Eller Well, and what is it?

Comment: @Eller   I interpret it as a document you would get from your driving school after successfully passing the practical driving test; this makes sense of course only in countries where you can appear to the practical test before having passed the written exam; I suppose there are countries where this is common.

Comment: PS: Or more explicitly: ***Bescheinigung der bestandenen Fahrprüfung***.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Interpreting is one thing but translation is another ;) To translate you should **know**, not interpret. This is why I have asked that.

Comment: @Eller  Yes, indeed, Nafmee should explain it a bit beyond the obvious (literal) meaning by describing the situation where such a document would be used or issued.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann That's right!

Comment: As Christian Geiselmann said "Simple practical driving test pass certificate".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Du meinst also, wir sollten in dem Wörterbuch nachschlagen, in dem wir auch Elfen, Kobolde, freie Energie, Willy-Brandt-Flughafen und Perpetuum mobile finden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting that apparently there is a term (see above the answer mentioning *Prüfbescheinigung*) I anyway want to suggest the following alternative neologisms:

> Fahrprüfungsbescheinigung
>
> Fahrprüfungszeugnis
>
> Fahrprüfungsschein
>
> Bescheinigung der bestandenen Fahrprüfung

Rationale: *Prüfbescheinigung* may be in use in the business indeed, but it is not intelligible for anybody outside (without the context) because it is completely unspecific. *Prüfbescheinigung* can also be a document issued by an engineer checking the soundness of whatever machinery, or the document issued by a chimneysweep after measuring exhaust gases of an oven and what not.

So, if the word is to be used in, say, fiction, a word that is more specific and self-contained such as the above would be the better choice.

Answer (score 3):

You may not find an answer to this question because such a thing does not exist. If you pass the practical driving exam, you've got your driving permission and you get the driving license. You are required to pass the theoretical exam before you can attempt a practical exam (at least I think that's also the case in germany). What the examiner does is sign off your learner's license so that it is valid as normal driving license until you get the final one shipped.

**Update**

The correct term seems to be "Prüfbescheinigung", see the comment from scienceponder. [Here's a link.](https://www.autoextrem.de/attachments/verkehrsrechtmagazin/40705d1151580720-pruefbescheinigung-scan10001.jpg) This form may be outdated, though.

Comment: It does not exist in Germany. What about other countries? And even such things can be translated.

Comment: I wouldn't translate a proper name. I would keep it as it is and add a word-for-word "translation" to explain it.

Comment: I have to contradict. "Such a thing" exists. It's called _Prüfbescheinigung_ and this is also how i would translate _practical driving test pass certificate._  One gets it right after passing the test, but before the actual licence is issued, e.g. the test can be done when one is still 17 years old, but the licence can not be obtained before the 18th birthday.

Comment: @scienceponder: Do you actually get a form with that name? I've never seen that.

Comment: @PMF Yes, you get that. The Fahrprüfer issues it right after the test. Without the Führerscheinstelle at Landratsamt, wich actually issues the license, would not have evidence that one passed.

See a picture here: [link](https://www.autoextrem.de/attachments/verkehrsrechtmagazin/40705d1151580720-pruefbescheinigung-scan10001.jpg)

Comment: @scienceponder: Ok, that's interesting. Gives the correct translation, although it may still be outdated (requirements for getting a driving license have changed significantly and multiple times in the last years)

Comment: Es gibt auch keine Einhörner aber dennoch ein Wort dafür. Über Zeus und Thor wird noch gestritten. Außerdem gibt es nicht nur das Fahren im Straßenverkehr, sondern auch Boote, Gabelstapler, ICEs und viele Spezialfahrzeuge verschiedener Berufe sowie Bedarf über Formulare, die es im Ausland gibt oder in der Vergangenheit gab, zu sprechen. "Praktischer Führerschein" liegt nahe.

Comment: "sign off your learner's license so that it is valid as normal driving license until you get the final one shipped" - what's a learner's license? At least when I had my practical exam in Germany around the year 2000, I had no documents (other than the contract with the driving school) until the day of the exam, and at the end of the exam, the examiner immediately gave me my final license. Nothing had to be shipped later on. That was several months after my 18th birthday already, though, maybe it makes a difference.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Here (Switzerland) you get a learner's permit, which allows you to drive when accompanied by somebody with a valid license (doesn't need to be a driving instructor) and after passing the theoretical exam (before about 2000, you could even drive before passing that). For your practical exam, you have to present this license and if you pass, the examiner will put his signature in it, making it a valid permit until the final one is shipped.